# POS Receipt / continuous paper printing in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement to print a receipt which is actually dynamically expand the content. I am using SSRS to design the report. I am using "Epson TM-T88V Thermal POS Receipt Printer" to print the content. I need a way to setup the page size dynamically as per the content length.

I googled alot but didn't find any way to print the report on continuous paper/receipt printer. It will be grateful if can help on this.

Comment: By dynamic, you only mean the length of the printing and not the width right? What happens when you print a receipt to it now? what have you tried? What is not working if anything?

Comment: Yes, I have a report with fixed width but the content length can be dynamic. So, I gone with some random size for the page height like 10in. But when i export to PDF there are lot of empty spaces after the content. I need to know if there's any workaround to fix the size of the export PDF to be same as the actual content length.

Comment: what about settings like consume container white space = True. Make the height of the report the smallest you can make.. i.i. if your header / logo and single line receipt was 5 cm then make the report 5 cm.. If you have additional items / lines.. it should automatically increase in size!